# Is there are any possible to increase the textsize and height of the PickerView or wheelview for selecting options like bottom sheet?

Tags: android, kotlin

Actually, I'm trying to implement the `MyOptionsPickerView`(single picker).
Need to change the text size and height by giving text size in dimensions to increase the text size in big screen. But I can't increase the height and text size in `MyOptionsPickerView` in `fragment`.

Comment: What is `MyOptionsPickerView`? i am not aware of such class in android SDK .. Pls edit ur question with proper details .

Comment: It's like a bottom sheet, options selected in a wheel view in kotlin, wheel view not expressed in layout xml.

Comment: Please provide screenshot or a link so the community can help you better.

Comment: https://images.app.goo.gl/4HiCC54nVU33qaJk9, link is here, it is like that in android kotlin. Single picker wheel view in koltin, without using wheel view in xml. Here, text size is fixed in default, can't give a text size in dimensions in it. It's view is perfect in mobile but in tab or big screen text size looks like small and also sheet's height also looks small.

Comment: I tried this  [  val wheelView = WheelView(requireContext())
                   wheelView.setTextSize(0.5f) ]  and                                                                           [ val txtSize : Float = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.txt_size)
        wheelView.setTextSize(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,txtSize, requireContext().getResources()?.getDisplayMetrics())) ]   but it's not working